# How to use mako template for divide?

Tags: python, mako

Assuming I have two variables "one" and "two" where they equal 1 and 2 respectively. How can I divide them in a mako template if possible? I want something like:

```
${"{0:.2f}".format(one/two)}
```

The result I want to output in the template is: 0.50

I am using python 2.x.

Comment: Try: `${"{0:.2f}".format(one//two)}`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan that'd force integer division in both 2.x and 3.x... so won't help in this case ;)

Comment: It appears anything less than 0 after the result shows up as 0. Is there a way to make it not do integer division and use decimals?

Comment: @JonClements can we use `${"{0:.2f}".format(float(one)/two)}` ? as we use in C

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes - or `operator.truediv(one, two)` - but alex has the correct approach here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `division` to `future_imports` argument of the `Template`:

```
>>> from mako.template import Template
>>> print Template("${a/b}").render(a=1, b=2)
0
>>> print Template("${a/b}", future_imports=['division']).render(a=1, b=2)
0.5
>>> print Template("${'{0:.2f}'.format(a/b)}", future_imports=["division"]).render(a=1, b=2)
0.50
```

Quote from [docs](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#mako.template.Template):

> `future_imports` – String list of names to import from `__future__`. These
>   will be concatenated into a comma-separated string and inserted into
>   the beginning of the template, e.g. `futures_imports=['FOO', 'BAR']`
>   results in `from __future__ import FOO, BAR`. If you’re interested in
>   using features like the new division operator, you must use
>   `future_imports` to convey that to the renderer, as otherwise the import
>   will not appear as the first executed statement in the generated code
>   and will therefore not have the desired effect.

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'future_imports'?

Comment: Nice material for me! I bookmarked this page as it is a bit complex to me now.

Comment: @Rolando `mako.__version__`? :)

Comment: @Rolando please upgrade to the latest version. `future_imports` was intoroduced in `0.8.0`: http://www.makotemplates.org/CHANGES.